# Determine if host is localhost

Tags: python, networking

I have a string `host` which can be a hostname (without domain), ipv4 address or ipv6 address.

Is there a simple way to determine if this refers to `localhost` loop-back device?

Python Version: 2.7

Comment: What is the value of `host` when working with localhost?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html ipaddress library has is_loopback method. This might help!

Comment: @AndyG The value of "host" is the value you see with `uname -a`. It is hostname without domain.

Comment: @VivekHarikrishnan we are still on Python2.7. AFAIK the ipaddress library is from Python3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check if IP address of the inputted host within [loopback address block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), `127.0.0.0/8` for IPv4, `::1` for IPv6:

```
import socket
import struct

def is_loopback(host):
    loopback_checker = {
        socket.AF_INET: lambda x: struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton(x))[0] >> (32-8) == 127,
        socket.AF_INET6: lambda x: x == '::1'
    }
    for family in (socket.AF_INET, socket.AF_INET6):
        try:
            r = socket.getaddrinfo(host, None, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.gaierror:
            return False
        for family, _, _, _, sockaddr in r:
            if not loopback_checker[family](sockaddr[0]):
                return False
    return True

for host in ('localhost', 'alias-of-localhost', 'google.com'):
    print host, is_loopback(host)
```

yields:

```
localhost True
alias-of-localhost True
google.com False
```

---

Update: there is [a python2 backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress) of python3 `ipaddress` library, you could replace checker part with checking against its `.is_loopback` property, internal logic is the same.

Comment: Yes, this works (the library). Thank you for the hint that there is the library `ipaddress` even for Python2!

Answer (score 0):

try this on Unix:

#### you need the subprocess module to find out the local hostname

import subprocess

hn = subprocess.Popen(['hostname'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
hn_out = hn.stdout.readline().strip('\n')

#### Test if "host" string is the IPv4 loop back address, IPv6 loop back address or if it's the local host name

if host == '127.0.0.1' or host == '::1' or host == hn_out:
    print("It's localhost")

Comment: I am unsure whether 127.0.0.2 is localhost, too.

Comment: I already have the string "host". I guess the subprocess part of your answer is not needed.

Comment: "_I am unsure whether 127.0.0.2 is localhost, too._" @guettli see the answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/44635/8499).